# Keeping a GET Response Stream Open

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm doing a GET request, and I don't want to ever close the Response stream. If there isn't anything to read I want to wait until there is.  How do I persist the stream, while keeping it open after a single GET request?

This is type of request I'm making. I am currently using ContinueWith to read the initial response, but the time between publishes is too long and the stream ends up closing.

```
streamer = new HttpClient()
{
  BaseAddress = new Uri("http://" + url + "/")
};
var get = streamer.GetStreamAsync(streamer.BaseAddress + "!" + Uri.EscapeDataString(query));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to post some NOP data into the stream periodically. In your client, you'd ignore the NOPs and only process the other data returned.

However, I'd like to point out this is a bad idea - that's not what HTTP is for. HTTP is built around request that have responses, as simple as that.

If you do actually need to use HTTP for some reason (e.g. your server is on a web hosting, or you need to use the 80 port), sending *some* data is more or less the only way. You could also specify larger timeouts, but it doesn't really help too much in practice. Another approach would be to do periodic polling on the client side, but that might be a lot harder to implement - it does fit the HTTP model a little better, though. A more reasonable way may be to use e.g. SignalR, which allows you to use an observer on the client to receive data from the server as it comes, automatically.

In the end, do note that there are no guarantees. HTTP isn't designed for this, and it's inherently unstable. It's designed to provide world-wide-web service, with proxies and local caches and what-not. You have to make sure caches are not used, and you have to be ready for the response to be closed, as simple as that. It can happen at any time, and so can e.g. an application pool restart. Be prepared to handle all those situations gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new thread and a function for the thread, in that function, you could create an infinite while cycle with a 1ms sleep at the end. Of course it wouldn't been infinite, because you could stop it with a variable. So in the while, you could re-request if the stream has closed.

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(connectionPending), 1);
function void connectionPending(object threadContext)
{
    while(waitForStream == true)
    {
        //re-request if stream is closed here

        Thread.Sleep(1); //sleep for 1ms.
    }
}
```

Not sure if there is any better way, I never really used HTTPClients.